# Ajax, Java and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web

I am looking for really good tutorials or even a book i can buy that will show me how to build a web application using Ajax framework, Spring (Java) and hibernate. Basically i just want to use AJAX for my front end and spring framework for my middle layer or business tier. For those with experience on these technologies please point me in the right direction. I already started to read Pro Ajax and Java by Nathaniel T. Schutta and Ryan Asleson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How experienced are you with web programming, and in Java programming? From your question seems like not very much.

Much of this can gets confusing if you are not yet comfortable with web and Java.

For the front end, AJAX requests are often done through JavaScripts (there are other ways to do this of course)

- [W3School Ajax Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)
- [Ajax Intro](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro2/)
- If you use jQuery for the front end, [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- I've also used [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org/)

And if you want to use Spring for your business layer, there's this blog about [Spring and AJAX](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/).

Have you ever used Spring before? There are lots of resources about Spring out there that are easy to find through searches, what component of Spring do you want to be using? its IOC capability? It's MVC framework? etc etc. And you can always read up on Spring 3 [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/)

and have you used ORM such as Hibernate before? Spring 3 uses Hibernate 4 and last time I was poking with it there were bugs in it and I had to drop back to Hibernate 3. You can read up on Hibernate from their [documentation page](http://www.hibernate.org/docs).

You are asking 3 different topics: AJAX, Spring and Hibernate - that's quite a bit to take in at once if you aren't really comfortable yet with Web and Java programming

Answer (score 0):

The Spring docs are very helpful: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/
It will tell you how all the pieces fit together.